# Remove checked property through jquery .model value not updated in knockout js

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I used the jquery to remove the checked property of checkbox.The UI value is updated.However, the model value is not updated. The same old value is there in the model. If I manually check unchecked checkbox the model value is updated. I have a scenario where one checkbox is click the other checkbox should be unchecked.The required functionality is done  through below code. But I need an updated value in the model.

```
answerClick: function (data, event) {
var element = event.target;
    $(element).parents('.primaryCaseMain').find("div#" + valueToHide).find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').removeAttr('checked');

}
```

Here is the HTML code

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="attr:{id: $data.Id , Qid: $parent.Id , Qref: $data.QuestionRefSetStrings , Uid: $data.Uid , rel: $data.MutuallyExclusive ? 'true' : 'false'} ,checked: $data.Selected, click: $root.answerClick , if: $root.appendQrefQuestion($data.QuestionRefSetStrings, $data.NoAppendRequiredQref)">
```

Comment: A better way is to update the model rather than the checkbox UI programmatically..

Answer (score 2):

You should use knockout to implemented this kind of functionality instead of jQuery.

In your viewmodel implement 2 properties, I call them `checkbox1` and `checkbox2`.

```
var self = this; //to have access to this in anonymous functions
this.checkbox1 = ko.observable(true);
this.checkbox2 = ko.observable(false);
```

Then subscribe to changes of each of the observables and set the value of the other observable to `false` if the set value is true.

```
this.checkbox1.subscribe(function(newValue){
    if(newValue){
        self.checkbox2(false);
    }
});

this.checkbox2.subscribe(function(newValue){
    if(newValue){
        self.checkbox1(false);
    }
});
```

Then use the `checked` binding to bind the properties to the `checkboxes`.

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: checkbox1" />
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: checkbox2" />
```

Comment: In checked binding I have a model value "$data.Selected". This value is the property of an obserable Array.How to implement on this? Also, all checkbox will be in foreach loop.So there will be multiple checkbox.

Comment: It just occurred to me, why dont you use `RadioButtons`?

Comment: If you want to use `Checkboxes`, you would have to create an array of observables and subscribe to each one. In the subscription function you would have to set the value of all other observables to false.

Comment: How to use a subscribe function with obserableArray. With checked binding as "$data.selected". Can you please show me.

Comment: Each entry of the must also be an observable. And you subscribe to each of these observables, not to the observable array. An observable array only notifies the UI on array changes (e.g. add, remove elements), so it is useless for this purpose.

Comment: @AnandaPrasadJaisy something like this http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/LkqTU/26810/